# how to scroll listview to last item on screen loading in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have created a simple demo to explain what i want..

I have a Listview builder which shows names,and a textfield for adding name to names list.

I have used following code for moving listview builder to last item while adding new name with IconButton,

```
 _scrollController.jumpTo(_scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent);
```

but how to scroll to last item when Screen loading...I placed above code in InitState() but its not working...

so how to do it without changing order of names..

here is my code

```
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  TextEditingController txtname = TextEditingController();
  final _scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                  controller: _scrollController,
                  itemCount: names.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
                        title: Text(names[index].toString()),
                      ))),
          Container(
            child: TextField(
              controller: txtname,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  suffix: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.send),
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        names.add(txtname.text);
                        _scrollController.jumpTo(
                            _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent);
                        txtname.clear();
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                  hintText: 'Enter Name'),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the Listview with a `SingleChildScrollView` and set the reading direction to reverse:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
        reverse: true,
        child: ListView.builder(
                  controller: _scrollController,
                  itemCount: names.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
                        title: Text(names[index].toString()),
  ))
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me,

So basically This function `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {...` ensures that a callback after the frame has been painted. and using `Timer` waits for the `ListView.builder` to be completed first. You can also add `FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();` to dismiss the keyboard

````
const HomeScreen({super.key});

@override
State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
TextEditingController txtname = TextEditingController();
final _scrollController = ScrollController();
@override
void initState() {
  print("sasssssss");
  super.initState();

  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 50), () {
      _scrollController.jumpTo(_scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent);
    });
  });
  print("sasssssss");
}

List names = List.generate(17, (index) => 'generated $index');

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
    // backgroundColor: Colors.red[100],
    body: Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
                controller: _scrollController,
                itemCount: names.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
                      title: Text(names[index].toString()),
                    ))),
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
          child: TextField(
            controller: txtname,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              suffix: IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.send),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    names.add("${txtname.text} Scrolled");
                    Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 50), () {
                      _scrollController
                          .jumpTo(_scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent);
                    });

                    txtname.clear();
                  });
                },
              ),
              hintText: 'Enter Name',
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ));
}
}```
````